# linecache error while creating python exe

Tags: py2exe

I am trying to create an exe of my Python application using py2exe. I am getting this error: "Import error: No module named linecache"
I've tried everything that has been suggested on this forum in the past, but nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Doesn't sound like anything related to `py2exe`. In any case, for the general case of `"Import error: No module named ..."`, the answer is as simple as it can be - you are trying to import a module which does not show up neither in the current path from which you are executing the python script, nor in Python environment's import path.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but I've already checked my environment variables. Also import linecache works smoothly on my shell. Still getting that error.

Comment: The error shows up only when I try executing (on Windows command) the exe file of my python application.

Comment: Well, `py2exe` does not handle certain things, for example, `__file__`. Maybe post your code here so that people can give it a try and tell you where the problem is.

Comment: I was getting frustrated......so used pyinstaller instead. Works like a charm! Thanks for your help anyway. But just in case, anyone knows a resolution to the py2exe problem, please post here.